# Cassandra keep using 100% of CPU and not utilizing memoery?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nosql

We have setup Cassandra single node of 3.11 with JDK 1.8 on ec2 with instance type t2.large which has 2 CPU and 7 GB of RAM.

We facing the issue that Cassandra keeps reaching CPU 100% even we do not have that much load.

We have 7GB of RAM but Cassandra not utilizing that Memory.it only uses 1.7-1.8 GB of RAM.

What configuration needs to change to reduce CPU utilization to not reach to 100%.
what best configuration to get better performance out of Cassandra.
Right now we able to get only about 100-120 read and 50-100 write operation per sec.

Please, some one helps us to understand the issue and what ways to improve performance configuration.

Comment: Are compactions running?  If so, you might try lowering the compaction throughput.

Comment: @Aaron - can you please give some input how can I capture compaction throughput so I can provide

Comment: `nodetool getcompactionthroughput` to check throughput.  If that doesn't reveal anything, check the value of concurrent compactors in your yaml.  First though, you need to determine *what* is causing your issue.  My guess is compaction or GC.

Comment: it comes as Current compaction throughput: 16 MB/s

Comment: in YAML compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

Comment: If you have verified that compactions are the issue, then lower it to 1 or 2, and see if it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152537/discussion-between-jayesh-and-aaron).

Comment: Whats your heap settings? Is Xmx set to 1.8GB?

Comment: I'm at work so I can't jump into chat.  Address Chris' question, check your system.log, and give this a read: https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html

Comment: @chris,@Aaron it was before 1024 now i have change to 5120M but still same behavior  -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M -Xms5120M -Xmx5120M -Xmn200M

Comment: from my option parameter  looks like its CMS -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000 -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled